# java_home is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your path error while developloing react native app for andriod in windows

Tags: java, android, reactjs, windows

i am trying to develope react native android app ,when i run cmd ->

```
react-native run-android
```

IT SHOWS ERROR

```
C:\Windows\System32\PropertyFinder>react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.

Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag
for more details.
```